# Excel-VBA: Need a function to select every 2nd value from a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user defined function which calculates payback period by taking two arguments: an outlay, and a range of inflows.

```
Public Function PayBackPeriod(outlay, inflow)
Dim i, yr As Integer
Dim cTotal As Double ' cumulative total
cTotal = 0

    For i = 1 To inflow.Count


    cTotal = cTotal + inflow.Cells(i).Value


    If cTotal = Abs(outlay) Then
    PayBackPeriod = i
    Exit Function
    End If
    If cTotal > Abs(outlay) Then
     yr = i - 1
     cTotal = cTotal - inflow.Cells(i).Value
     PayBackPeriod = yr + (Abs(outlay) - (cTotal)) / inflow.Cells(i).Value

     Exit Function

    End If
    Next i
    PayBackPeriod = "Not enough return to Payback!!!"
```

The issue is now that my range of inflows has a dollar amount AND a percent next to it, so I really need to pull every second value. I tried adding "Step 2" after the line:

```
'cTotal = cTotal + inflow.Cells(i).Value Step 2`
```

but this doesn't seem to be working...Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance...
[image]

Comment: Can you define in which way it is 'not working'?

Comment: Put your step 2 in the for statement `For i = 1 To inflow.Count Step 2`?

Comment: Of course, my apologies. So it is running, but it is giving me an answer that makes no sense...It's returning a payback period that's longer than what it should be. Prior to my altering the format of the range it uses as in inflow, it returned an appropriate answer...

Comment: @ScottCraner, this doesn't seem to do it either...

Comment: Step through the code, and make sure it is pulling the right values. Maybe you need to start at i = 2 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping over the `Cells`, loop over the `Rows` (assuming `inflow` is a n rows x 2 cols range)

```
For i = 1 To inflow.Rows.Count

    'work with inflow.Rows(i)

Next i
```

If your input is 2 rows x n columns:

```
For i = 1 To inflow.Columns.Count

    'work with inflow.Columns(i)

Next i
```

Comment: the inflows go across the columns. Should I replace the rows with columns in the previous code?

Comment: How are the values arranged in the `inflow` range?  Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a better way, but I posted a screenshot on the original question. The red box is the outflow, and the yellow boxes are the inflows i need to select

Comment: After seeing your screenshot @scottcraner's comment should work.  I was assuming your input range was a different shape.

Comment: By input range, do you mean the outflows? If so, yes, its a single cell

Comment: No I meant the inflow range.